# Easy mechanic question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

A man is walking down a street, he wants to avoid touching any rain drops. Walking with a velocity of $v$ and rain drops falling at $u$. He has an umbrella with radius of $r$ and his height is $h$. What radius should his umbrella have to avoid touching?

My answer was that I visualised the umbrella as a flat horizontal surface up on his head, then when the rain drop reach near to the umbrella one end, then since the umbrella has a height too: $ut = h$ and $vt = r \implies (h/u)\times v = r$ but apparently I should have visualised the umbrella with an angle $\theta$ between the height an $r$ and then I should have solved that, my question is why is my answer wrong?

Comment: Please avoid homework questions that are specific rather than conceptual.

Comment: @QuantumYitian this is not a homework question per se - and even if, that does not matter. The OP rightfully does not understand why his correct solution which he presents to us here is not considered valid.

Comment: Is the angle $\theta$ the angle the rain makes with the walking man? Or is it the tilt of his umbrella?

Comment: @MarkH sorry for the late response, between the umbrella and persons body

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. Your teachers just don't appreciate the universality of physics and that there are often many ways to get to answer.

The results are the same, of course.